# How to canonically create a brand new object in Python

Tags: python-2.7

Is there a way to create a brand new object with canonic operations ? I am a bit confused by the example below :

```
x = 1
y = int.__new__(int, 1)
print x is y

>> True
```

**EDIT :**

[“is” operator behaves unexpectedly with integers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/306313/is-operator-behaves-unexpectedly-with-integers) enlights the example above, but doesn't answer the question about the existence of a canonic way to create two different `int` objects. In the end, it just helps to understand that writing `x = 256; y = 256` is *not* a solution, which is not what I was looking for.

Comment: The point is that x and y are references that are pointing to the same thing

Comment: I took your code a step further and assigned 2 to x and learned that x is not y any longer.  This concept about references is critical to understanding some potential gotcha's in Python

Comment: I'm confused by the example as well... the `x is y` bit is (I think) a CPython specific optimization and demonstrates it _not_ creating a brand new object.  What was the example _supposed_ to show?

Comment: @PyNEwbie you need to read up on immutable vs mutable - integers are the former. See http://nedbatchelder.com/text/names.html

Comment: @jonrsharpe Great link

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> Is there a way to create a brand new object with canonic operations ?

[For the object `1`?  No.  For other integers, yes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/306313/is-operator-behaves-unexpectedly-with-integers).  In python, objects are references that point to an instance of an object.  An `int` in python is an object that exists on the heap, and all python variables that are `1` are really object references that point to a heap object (which stores the `int` object).  In python, **all numbers between -5 and 256 have dedicated `int` objects so that the references to them are always equal**.

[In Python's documentation](http://docs.python.org/c-api/int.html):

> The current implementation keeps an
>   array of integer objects for all
>   integers between -5 and 256, when you
>   create an int in that range you
>   actually just get back a reference to
>   the existing object. So it should be
>   possible to change the value of 1. I
>   suspect the behaviour of Python in
>   this case is undefined. :-)

For more clarification, [see this SO post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6158907/what-does-python-treat-as-reference-types), that really all types in python are value types.