# List is immutable? Cannot convert list of strings ---> list of floats

Tags: python, string, list, floating-point, immutability

I have a list of values, titled 'list', with values 23.4158, 25.3817, 26.4629, 26.8004, 26.6582, 27.7, 27.8476, 28.025.  Each value is a string, not a float.  Thus, I would like to convert this to a list of floats.

When I create a for loop to reassign the strings as floats, using the float() function, within the loops it shows me that the str has been successfully converted to a float.  But when I check the type outside the loop, it shows me they are still strings.

```
for i in list:
    i = float(i)
    print(i,"=", type(i))
print(type(list[0]))
```

HOWEVER.  When I create an empty list (new_list), and append the converted floats into said list, it shows exactly what I want.  In other words, the str--->float conversion is successful.  Code as such:

```
new_list = list()
for i in list:
    i = float(i)
    print(i,"=", type(i))
    new_list.append(i)
print(type(new_list[0]))
```

Why is it that the reassignment does not 'stick' unless the values are appended to new_list? Lists are mutable, so the old list should be able to be modified.  Am i missing something?

Answer (score 2):

The reassignment does not "stick" because you are not converting the item inside the list, you are converting `i`, which is another value inside the loop, completely detached from the `list` object. You are just converting a new variable `i` to `float`, you are not converting the item from within the list. The variable `i` is a new variable and python just copied the **value** from the item inside the new variable `i`. You are not converting the item from the list, you are converting a new variable `i` that has the same value as the item that the loop is currently at.

If you want to convert the item from withing the list using a for loop, you must target the item itself using its index:

```py
values = [
    "23.4158", "25.3817", "26.4629", "26.8004", "26.6582", "27.7", "27.8476", "28.025"
]

for i in range(len(values)):
    values[i] = float(values[i])

print(values)
print(type(values[0]))
```

The reason why it works when appending to a list is because you are appending the newly converted `i`, which indeed, is a float.

I suggest reading the following:

- [What does Python treat as reference types?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6158907/what-does-python-treat-as-reference-types)
- https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/pass-by-reference-vs-value-in-python/
- https://www.tutorialsteacher.com/csharp/csharp-value-type-and-reference-type